# from xlutils.copy import copy ImportError: No module named copy

Tags: python, xlutils

I want to modify the existing worksheet.
When I input

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
```

then I got

```
ImportError: No module named copy
```

I have try reinstall xlutils from different ways, it still doesn't work.
Lib\site-packages\xlutils\copy.py is also existing.
How can I do about this?
thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried both

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlutils import copy
```

both works. It seems your python lib is not in your lib path. try the following code:

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

and check if your lib path is there. if not add the lib path using:

```
sys.path.append('/your-lib-path')
```

in python code, or add the lib path to your environment variable PYTHONPATH